# Not able to click button on website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to programmatically click the hidden button below:

```html
<p>
    <img class="getdata-button" style="float:right;" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" id="get" onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()">
    <input type="button" value="Get Results" tabindex="9" id="submitMe" onclick="submitData();" style="display:none" ;="">
</p>
```

I tried the following in Python:

```py
sub_driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe")
sub_driver.find_element_by_id("get").click()
sub_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id=\"submitMe\"]")
sub_driver.execute_script("javascript:submitData();")
sub_driver.find_element_by_class_name('getdata-button').click()
my_var=sub_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button'][@id='submitMe']").click
sub_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",my_var)
```

But the code is either hanging or not finding the element.

Comment: this markup is problematic: style="display:none" ;=""   No idea why that last part is there... but display set to none means it's not visible and Selenium can't click it.

Comment: I tried with executing 'console' option in inspect with $('#submitMe') it works in console. But when tried same with execute script option in code it is not executing

Comment: maybe click the <img> element instead... not sure if that'll work while the display is set to none and the tag itself is invalid.